# Wallet problem and ASIC miner

Tags: wallet, asic

I bought an ASIC miner but the wallet just cannot get synched. I am trying for days now and i am still 18 weeks back. Can i run my ASIC miner on a pool, while my wallet isn't fully synched and the blockchain isn't fully downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you should be running something like [cgminer](https://github.com/ckolivas/cgminer) or [bfgminer](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer) which can join a pool and mine while your client is still downloading the blockchain.  You only need your own blockchain to do solo mining, and unless you are running a lot of very fast asics you will want to continue mining in the pool.